# ruby on rails 3 scope extensions and includes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I am experimenting with scope extensions and was wondering if I could do something like this.

```
class User  
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :klass      

  scope :users_in_klass, lambda {|k|  where(:klass_id => k)} do

    def current_task_report
      includes(:tasks)
      users = []
      each {|u|
        user = {
          :name => u.full_name,
          :id => u.id,
          :tasks => u.tasks
        }
        users << user
      }
      users
    end

end
```

And call it like this

```
u = User.users_in_klass(6899)
u.current_task_report
```

The problem I'm having is that it's ignoring the includes on the tasks for eager loading.

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`klass_id` = 6899)
Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.user_id = 46539)
Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.user_id = 46909)
Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.user_id = 46910)
```

Is what I'm am doing correct?

On a side note, Is there a better place to put the current_task_report method?

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the includes statement into your lambda

```
class User  
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :klass      

  scope :users_in_klass, lambda {|k| includes(:tasks).where(:klass_id => k)} do

    def current_task_report
      users = []
      each {|u|
        user = {
          :name => u.full_name,
          :id => u.id,
          :tasks => u.tasks
        }
        users << user
      }
      users
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this association to your Klass:

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  has_many :tasks, :through => :users

end
```

Then getting the current task report would look something like this:

```
Klass.find(6899).tasks
```

I am assuming Rails will be smart enough to automatically do an "IN" statement in the resulting query.

Comment: Sorry that my example is over simplified, I dumbed it down too much. I am wanting to do more than just get the tasks. I was wondering why the includes(:tasks) method doesn't work seeing as up until then, the query hadn't been run.